# In sharepoint 2013 , product catalog - How to programmatically add a tag to the Item Category column in the product list?

Tags: 2013

I have a custom webpart to add an item to the product list, i need a way to add tags to the item catagory column in the list (programmatically).

How do I do it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i figured out a way to do this 
      TaxonomyFieldValueCollection TagsCat = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(String.Empty);
                                TagsCat.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(TaxonomyWebTaggingControl1.Text);

```
                            var taxKeywordField = oSpListItem.Fields.GetField("ProductCatalogItemCategory") as TaxonomyField;
                            taxKeywordField.CreateValuesInEditForm = true;
                            try
                            {
                                taxKeywordField.ParseAndSetValue(oSpListItem, TagsCat[0].TermGuid);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e2)
                            {

                            }
                            oSpListItem.Update();
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at these scripts on TechNet. The script starting with 5 is updating the Item Category column. http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Import-list-content-to-f735d7fb